# ARKit – How to apply a filter on a specific portion of Scene View?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I am new to ARKit. I want to add a node or frame on ARKit plane on tap and want to show some visual effects on the camera in that frame only. I have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhRR4.jpg).

Here's a [sample video](https://vimeo.com/441930763) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this effect use [CIFilters](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIMaskedVariableBlur) with alpha channel applied, and [SCNTechnique](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntechnique) class.

Here's a [sample project](https://github.com/2RKowski/ARSCNViewImageFiltersExample/blob/master/ARSCNViewImageFiltersExample/ViewController.swift).

Comment: i need to transparent visual effects, it shows solid colour on SCNNode

Comment: Then apply filters to a view, not to nodes.

Comment: but i need to show those filters on frame of node only, not on whole scene view, and it should also be transparent so that i can see scene view's camera view behind the node as filtered

Comment: Anyway, It's a compositing technique requiring CIFilters... It doesn't depend on whether it's a node or a view...